# Detect scrolling direction in a page with disabled rubber band effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 980px;
    padding: 0; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

This is the css I'm using to prevent macos rubber band scrolling. Also I want to detect the direction of the scroll, down or up.

```
var iScrollPos = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var iCurScrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (iCurScrollPos > iScrollPos) {
        console.log('down');
    } else {
        console.log('up');
    }
    iScrollPos = iCurScrollPos;
});
```

But `$(window)` is not a relevant element, because of the CSS.

Comment: You need to listen for the scroll event on the element being scrolled:  `$('body').scroll(...`

Comment: I tried this, but `$('body').scrollTop()` returns always `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to disable `rubber band` scrolling and detect the scrolling direction.

[jquery.mousewheel.js](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/) and this js

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    if(delta > 0 )
       console.log('up');
    else
       console.log('down');
});
```

**Note**: It only detects if the user is using the `mouse wheel` to scroll the page.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 // overflow: hidden;  -remove this line
}
```

working sample

http://jsbin.com/iKaQuzO/1/edit

Comment: I cannot remove this line, because the `rubber band` effect returns. And I do not need it.